# pointer converting in initialization

Tags: c++, qt, casting

I have a class `MyClass` in which there is one function that returns a pointer to `QString`:

```
QString* MyClass::generateName()
```

In other function I want to make a functions pointers' array with `generateName()` in it. When I write

```
QString* (*array[1])() = {&MyClass::generateName};
```

I am getting an error:

```
cannot convert ‘QString* (MyClass::*)()’ to ‘QString* (*)()’ in initialization
```

When I remove `MyClass::` from the array definition, it only gives me another error about the ISO. Besides, the former error remains.

What am I supposed to do to get rid of the error?

Comment: Read about member function pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First with function pointers you should use typedefs:

```
typedef QString* (MyClass::* funcType)();
```

Then, an array is easy to define:

```
funcType myArray[] = { &MyClass::generateName };
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you're looking for to define an array of member function pointers is:

```
QString* (MyClass::*array[1])() = {&MyClass::generateName};
```

The only difference to normal function pointers is that for a member function pointer you must give the class name in the type:

```
ReturnType* (ClassType::*)(ArgTypes)
```